# New Badge Banner

Tags: support, badges, notifications

I received the [electorate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/155/electorate) badge sometime today but I didn't get the whizz bang banner congratulating me on this awesome achievement.

I don't know if there is anyway for you to check whether a banner has been displayed or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[They've dialled back the cornucopia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta/96955#96955) of top banner loads for some of the lesser badge notifications.

> We're also hiding several badge notifications based on if you're associated ("veteran") or not (the clutter ones like autobiographer that you get immediately as well).

Looks like Electorate isn't one of the fiesta guests.

Comment: Ah I didn't spot this change - thanks. It's a shiny Gold badge too, I thought that would be worthy of a whizz bang banner.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there was a bug in the code that suppressed message for all badges not just bronze ones:

[System message indicating badge was awarded was not displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99082/system-message-indicating-badge-was-awarded-was-not-displayed/99087#99087)

You should have had the notification for the gold badge.

Comment: Ah I see - thought it was bit strange for all badges. Cheers